# Regex can't escape characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So here is the regex:

```
$reg_exUrl = "(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
```

Here is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in
```

Still can't find a solution how to use this in my code, how I need to escape it in order to be stored in a variable?

Comment: you could always use `preg_quote();` on non regex text http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: This is why editors with syntax coloring are invaluable. A second glance at the code in the OP make in the most novice of devs aware of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

escape the double quote in the regexp

```
$reg_exUrl = "(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in

Comment: please update your post with the code, i.e. where this $reg_exUrl variable is used further.